# How to build excerpt functionality in angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm creating small blogging system in AngularJS + RoR for backend.

I have a posts stored in my db and the content of a post is stored in the "Content" column. Example of content column data is this.

```
<p>Hello how are you doing?</p><p>how about you?</p>
```

I want to show all of my blog posts on the homepage, like a newsfeed. Of course I don't want to show whole post content of each post. Let's say that I want to show only first 100 characters of post content.

so far I managed to trim the html tags from the string i'm displaying via custom filter

```
angular.module('flapperNews').
  filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
    };
  }
);
```

and it is used like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content | htmlToPlaintext"></div>
```

but the output looks like this

```
Hello how are you doing?how about you?
```

as you probably noticed there are no spaces between sentences now.

Is there any way how to fix that, or do you know about any other way how to add excerpt functionality to an angular app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the tag not with `''`, but with a space:

```
angular.module('flapperNews').
  filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, ' ') : ''; // replace with a space
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: I think that i'll add more functionality to the filter later, but for now this will do. Thank you :)